# Bot framework SDK4 - node.js after Login every message sending user greetings

Tags: node.js, authentication, bots, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am developing a bot where users are authenticating, after succesfull authentication user are seeing No Kb found as the code they entered is going for qna maker search and  every time user search for kb they are getting welcome message

Here is my Sample Code

```
import { ConfirmPrompt, DialogSet, DialogTurnStatus, OAuthPrompt, WaterfallDialog,ChoicePrompt } from 'botbuilder-dialogs';
 
import { StatePropertyAccessor,UserState } from 'botbuilder';
import { LogoutDialog } from './logoutDialog';
import { SimpleGraphClient } from '../../services/graphClient';

import { polyfills } from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {appVariables,PromptNames,appLabels,StateVariables} from '../../values'
import {Dialogs} from '../Dialogs'
import {QnAMakerBaseDialog} from './CqnaMakerDialog'
import {GetRegions} from '../utils/qnaFIlters'
const {connectionName} = appVariables
const {SIGN_IN_TEXT,SIGN_IN_TITLE} = appLabels

export class MainDialog extends LogoutDialog {
    private welcomedUserProperty: StatePropertyAccessor<boolean>;
    private userState: UserState;
    
    /**
     *
     * @param {UserState} User state to persist boolean flag to indicate
     *                    if the bot had already welcomed the user
     */
    constructor(userState: UserState) {
        super(Dialogs.MAIN_DIALOG, connectionName);
        
        this.welcomedUserProperty = userState.createProperty(StateVariables.WELCOMED_USER);
        this.userState = userState;
        this.addDialog(new QnAMakerBaseDialog())
        this.addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(PromptNames.oauth, {
            connectionName: connectionName,
            text: SIGN_IN_TEXT,
            title: SIGN_IN_TITLE,
            timeout: 300000
        }));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(PromptNames.confirm));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(Dialogs.MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.promptStep.bind(this),
            this.loginStep.bind(this),
        ]));
        
       
        this.initialDialogId = Dialogs.MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    /**
     * The run method handles the incoming activity (in the form of a DialogContext) and passes it through the dialog system.
     * If no dialog is active, it will start the default dialog.
     * @param {*} dialogContext
     */
    async run(context, accessor) {
        const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.add(this);
        const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
        const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
        if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        }

    }

    async promptStep(stepContext) {
        try {
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(PromptNames.oauth);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    async loginStep(stepContext) {
        
        const tokenResponse = stepContext.result;
        if (!tokenResponse || !tokenResponse.token) {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Login was not successful please try again.');
        } else {
            
                const client = new SimpleGraphClient(tokenResponse.token);
                const me = await client.getMe();
                const title = me ? me.jobTitle : 'UnKnown';
                const regionFilter = GetRegions(me.officeLocation)
                await stepContext.beginDialog(Dialogs.QNA_MAKER_BASE_DIALOG,regionFilter)
                await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`You're logged in as ${me.displayName} (${me.userPrincipalName}); your job title is: ${title};`);    
        }
        return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }

    
}
```

After Succesful login initially authcode is automatically passed to qna maker for search where i am getting **No KB Articles** message and other is always when i search for KB articles always i am getting user greeting

`You are logged in as <username>`

In the Dialog Bot onmessage event calling mainDialog Run causing the issue, Code for DialogBot

```
export class DialogBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    conversationState;
    userState;
    dialog;
    dialogState;
    /**
     *
     * @param {ConversationState} conversationState
     * @param {UserState} userState
     * @param {Dialog} dialog
     */
    constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super();
        if (!conversationState) {
            throw new Error('[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. conversationState is required');
        }
        if (!userState) {
            throw new Error('[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. userState is required');
        }
        if (!dialog) {
            throw new Error('[DialogBot]: Missing parameter. dialog is required');
        }

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty('DialogState');

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');

            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);

            await next();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Override the ActivityHandler.run() method to save state changes after the bot logic completes.
     */
    async run(context) {
        await super.run(context);

        // Save any state changes. The load happened during the execution of the Dialog.
        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false);
        await this.userState.saveChanges(context, false);
    }

    
}
```